# controller dependencies in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular and when I read tutorials I see two different methods of declaring dependencies in controllers:

1)

```
angular.module("myApp",[]).controller('MyController, function($scope, $localStorage){
});
```

And others have a little different way:

2)

```
angular.module("myApp",[]).controller('MyController, ['$scope', '$localStorage', function($scope,$localStorage){
}]);
```

The second way seems to be redundant to me since I have to specify $scope and $localStorage twice? What is the difference between these two ways of defining a controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second way is minification friendly. When your code is minified

```
angular.module("myApp",[]).controller('MyController, function($scope, $localStorage){
});
```

will turn into something like

```
angular.module("myApp",[]).controller('MyController, function(a,b){
});
```

The second way keeps a reference to the object you are passing in. You can [check the docs here](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05), scroll down to "a note on minification"

Comment: If you want to have more details on what Kevin is talking about, see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di (Dependency Annotation). You have an explanation on the three ways of declaring your components with the pros and cons ;)